# IdeaVim remapping not working for CloseActiveEditor

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, ideavim

I'm using IdeaVim and WebStorm and I want to map closing the active editor to:

```
nnoremap <leader>tc :action CloseActiveEditor<CR>
```

and also map reopening the closed editor to:

```
nnoremap <leader>to
```

Why do mappings like the below work but the two above don't?

```
nnoremap <leader>tn :action NextTab
```

I tried remapping the said actions above but they just won't work in my WebStorm session. I saved the files and restarted WebStorm after each change to be sure but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `CloseActiveEditor` action. You can see the full action list via `:actionlist`.

It should be `nnoremap <leader>tc <Action>(CloseContent)`.

> nnoremap to

I guess you want `nnoremap <leader>to <Action>(ReopenClosedTab)` there.